# How to use Ganache, Remix IDE, MetaMask, and Web3js without Truffle

Tags: solidity, remix, ganache

I am having an issue migrating a contract using Oraclize API to Ganache from Truffle.

However, everything is working fine when running the contract from Remix IDE via MetaMask. As I want to write the frontend of the dapp, how to do that without migrating the contract into Ganache from Truffle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use contract you can use web3js only. Create instance of contract

```
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(<ABI>, '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe');
```

Take a look the documentation
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html

Comment: Am I understanding it correctly, that I need to first deploy the contract to Ganache from Remix, than copy the ABI from Remix to my a JS file and then import it to the  var MyContract?

Comment: yes. deploy -> copy ABI and address -> put in dapp -> instantiate contract -> communicate with the contract

Comment: Do you know how does this work in React? Do I have to instantiate this once when the component will mount? And is that the address of the contract owner?

Comment: You can instantiate in didMount event or globally. That address is contract address.